# Source for 'startup files' in gcc/mingw

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, disassembly

Im using mingw32

In gcc there is an option

```
" -nostartfiles  Do not use the standard system startup files when linking. The standard system libraries are used normally, unless -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs is used. "
```

If i do not use it in my itself almost empty c source i got in my exe 1000-lines disasembly long stub of code containing such functions

```
00401000 <___mingw_CRTStartup>:
00401110 <__gnu_exception_handler@4>:
00401280 <_mainCRTStartup>:
004012a0 <_WinMainCRTStartup>:
004012c0 <_atexit>:
004012d0 <__onexit>:
004012e0 <___gcc_register_frame>:
0040132c <___gcc_deregister_frame>:
00401334 <_WinMain@16>:
00401340 <___dyn_tls_dtor@12>:
00401390 <___dyn_tls_init@12>:
00401420 <___tlregdtor>:
00401430 <___cpu_features_init>:
00401510 <__fpreset>:
00401520 <___report_error>:
00401580 <___write_memory.part.0>:
00401690 <__pei386_runtime_relocator>:
00401870 <___do_global_dtors>:
004018a0 <___do_global_ctors>:
004018f0 <___main>:
00401910 <___mingwthr_run_key_dtors.part.0>:
00401970 <____w64_mingwthr_add_key_dtor>:
00401a00 <____w64_mingwthr_remove_key_dtor>:
00401a90 <___mingw_TLScallback>:
00401b30 <___getmainargs>:
00401b38 <__setmode>:
00401b40 <___p__fmode>:
00401b48 <___p__environ>:
00401b50 <__cexit>:
00401b58 <_signal>:
00401b60 <_fwrite>:
00401b68 <_vfprintf>:
00401b70 <_abort>:
00401b78 <_memcpy>:
00401b80 <_calloc>:
00401b88 <_free>:
00401b90 <_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4>:
00401b98 <_ExitProcess@4>:
00401ba0 <_GetModuleHandleA@4>:
00401ba8 <_GetProcAddress@8>:
00401bb0 <_VirtualQuery@12>:
00401bb8 <_VirtualProtect@16>:
00401bc0 <_GetCommandLineA@0>:
00401bc8 <_GetStartupInfoA@4>:
00401bd0 <_EnterCriticalSection@4>:
00401bd8 <_TlsGetValue@4>:
00401be0 <_GetLastError@0>:
00401be8 <_LeaveCriticalSection@4>:
00401bf0 <_DeleteCriticalSection@4>:
00401bf8 <_InitializeCriticalSection@4>:
00401c00 <_main>:
00401ce0 <_register_frame_ctor>:
00401cfc <__CTOR_LIST__>:
00401d00 <.ctors.65535>:
00401d08 <__DTOR_LIST__>:
```

Could maybe someone say where i could find source for that?
(or at least some detailed explanation what is that - but source would be better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could download [GCC sources](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [MinGW sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/).

Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org I suggest also to check [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org) and then run `grep` or similar text search utility and find particular file(s) where those function(s) are defined.

Note also that some functions like `exit()`, `atexit()`, `memcpy()`, etc. are coming from C Run-Time Library, they won't be defined in GCC sources.

Comment: great, though if you got avaliable skills could you maybe help a bit far longer and try to find it and say where it is (or if you found it?)

Comment: @user2214913 ok, I have git installed from http://git-scm.com/download/win. Cloned official mingw-w64 repo from sourceforge, executing `git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64 mingw-w64-mingw-w64`. Go into `mingw-w64-mingw-w64` directory and in Explorer searched for `do_global_ctors`, and it pointed me to `mingw-w64-mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\crt\gccmain.c`, here one can find `do_global_dtors` as well

Comment: Sources on disk aer about 130Mb, git packed it all in transfer, so you download about 30Mb or so, `git clone ...` is executed in the terminal window