# When is the gcc flag -nostartfiles used?

Tags: gcc

I can't seem to figure out the purpose of the flag `-nostartfiles`.  It prevents `main()` from being called immediately, and typically you'd also specify the program entry point.  However, why would I want to do that?  I have written a kernel that required it, since everything was up to me to get started, but other than that, is there a non-OS reason to specify a different program entry point?

Comment: "I have written a kernel that required it, since everything was up to me to get started" - you answered your own question.

Comment: Well, yes.  What I meant was, is there any reason other than kernel writing (see the last part of the question).  If not, then I guess I **do** understand it better than I thought :-P

Comment: Microcontrollers, using the compiler as a cross compiler and preventing libraries from being used since there is no operating system to back them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd use `-nostartfiles` (and `-nostdlib`) when you do not want any standard libraries (like libc and libgcc) to be linked in and standard initialization actions, like calling C++ constructors, to be run. Typical use-cases are writing system software like kernels or firmwares.

Comment: Another use-case is when you are building the start files themselves.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that with `-nostartfiles` command line arguments will not be passed to `main()` and environment variables will not be available to the executable, among other things. Docker uses `-nostartfiles` in an example where a single binary is run within a simple container, i.e., where the container is run like a single binary: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/, so that is another use case.

Slightly related is [Source for 'startup files' in gcc/mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460420/source-for-startup-files-in-gcc-mingw), which lists functions that are linked into to the code if `-nostartfiles` option is not used.