# Do I need the C runtime library if I don't call any standard library functions?

Tags: c++, c

If I give an executable file (a program on Windows) to a friend and they try to execute it, and get a message saying that the program could not find the C runtime libraries, is that because in the source code I wrote I made a call to the standard library? If I write a simple program that enters main and does things that doesn't call a standard library function, no malloc, no printf, nothing, will that error message no longer pop up? Is this the same in C and C++? What does the runtime library do in these cases where I don't call any library functions? Is it needed at program startup to initialise the program, like a kind of header that tells the CPU or the OS how to run the program? I'm asking in relation to C and C++.

Comment: "If I write a simple program that enters main" ... dealing with `main()` is part of the C Standard Library :-)

Comment: On Windows if you only use Win32 functions and set the entry point correctly it is possible to not require the runtime library. It's a chore. Less so for a GUI program, but also possible for console. We do this for our installer to keep it very small. Easier to just static link your program though.

Comment: @pmg Maybe not in terms of the C Standard description of library functions. But yeah, with typical compile/link/run systems some minimal libraries are needed as part of "the implementation" even if those named functions are not directly used.

Comment: @aschepler C runtime library isn't the same as C standard library.. although pmg is mentioning the standard one, I guess mistakenly.

Comment: @RetiredNinja *On Windows if you only use Win32 functions...*  That just replaces one runtime library with another.  As far as static linking, Windows at least has a stable API with forward-compatibility guarantees...

Comment: @AndrewHenle No it doesn't. The Win32 DLL files are present on all machines. If you only use functions from those there are no additional dependencies that must be installed.

Comment: FWIW, you (usually) don't use the runtime library on embedded bare-metal targets. There are special switches to GCC as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050089/when-is-the-gcc-flag-nostartfiles-used). But you will need to provide your own low-level startup code jumping to `main`.

Comment: @Zebrafish It is possible that the error message will not appear.  Much depends on the _compiler_, not the OS.

Comment: You don't need the standard libraries, if you don't directly use them **nor does anything else**.  Check your compiler documentation.  A lot of the embedded systems compilers allow you to piecemeal the functionality in the standard library.  If you use any streaming, all bets are off.

Comment: Compilers for platforms that have a lot of memory and resources will by default throw a lot of common functionality into a library, *whether you use it or not*.  This makes the build a lot faster and development time faster (you don't need to roll your own stuff).

Comment: It is perhaps an X-Y problem, perhaps the simpler solution to the original problem is to statically link the C runtime, so everything you need is included in the executable rather than relying on any DLLs.  Alternatively have your friend install the appropriate [vcredist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)

Comment: The C standard does not specify what the runtime, if any, should do. It's up to the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked the question with both C an C++ tags, I shall try to speak of both.

1. For both language:

   The standard and/or runtime libraries are required as soon as you use `main` as the entry point. And whether the code running main is statically or dynamically linked in your program is an implementation detail and can depend on your platform.

   Of course if you do not use `main`, you will have to provide an entry point (depending on the platform) and explicitely handle program termination (again platform dependant)

   That being said, AFAIK MSVC on Windows will statically link the entry point code, so a program containing only `int main() { return 0;}` should not require any additional DLL.
2. C specific:

   Some features of the C language, like io or dynamic allocation depend on the standard library, but that dependance is explicit. That means that before using any function from the standard library, you should have to explicitely declare it, either directly or through an include file. So if your code never direcly or indirectly include any of the headers from the standard library, you program will not require any access from a DLL.

   On Windows, `#include <windows.h>` does not include any header from the C standard library.
3. C++ specific:

   Some *instructions* from C++ language do depend on the standard library. For example any dynamic allocation/deallocation instruction like `new`, `new[]`, `delete` or `delete[]` are implemented through calls to the standard library. That means that the library will be required if you use those instructions, even without using any standard include...
4. WinAPI:

   On Windows, the functions from the WinAPI shall be present on any Windows system, and portability is carefully handled across releases. So if you only use functions from WinAPI *that exist on the older system you target* you will have no DLL dependency problem, even if you do not statically link the standard library.
5. Static linking:

   For both languages, all the major platforms allow for static linking of the standard library through configuration options. And this is enough for your code not to depend from any dynamic library. So it is probably the better option unless for C GUI programs.

Answer (score 1):

C runtime requires that you use a `main()` function to be provided by you to do whatever you want to do.  This requires you to link your program object files with a special file, that does the housekeeping required by C programs to allow it to finally call your main routine with the C environment ready.  This program will most probably do several operating system calls that can be (not necessarily are, but can be) tied to C runtime functions that are part of the C standard library, and this ties you to the standard library.

Also, it is very strange that your program will not comunicate with the system.  The first thing you will probably need to do is to access C functions to do environment things (e.g. get the system time, print something to standard output, or even `exit()` the program) are functions that reside in the C standard library.

If your program has been linked dynamically against the standard library (this means, you have a dynamic executable that requires some libraries to be available at runtime) you must provide copies of those to the target environment, and to put all those libraries in the proper place (in windows that is somewhere in Windows system directory) or probably next to the main executable, in order to be able to execute the program.

Another option you have is to build a statically linked executable (this is, one that uses no dynamically linked libraries) but that's not practical, because this means the libraries the program uses are not shared between program instances and so, you will fill all your computer memory with different copies of the same library, in use by the different programs.  And your programs will get far larger than using dynamic linking.

My recommendation is for you to get all the libraries your program needs in the system you developed it, and package all of them to be sent with your program.  The advantage of this approach is that, once done so, if you send more and more C programs to your target system, you will not need to provide new copies of them, because the system will load the only copy of the neede library once for every program that uses it.

Of course your program can be written in assembler, and use no library to provide the services you need.  This way, you will not be able to `printf()` with buffered output, you will not be able to do proper reading of input with `scanf()`, `fgets()`, `read()`, etc.  Because all of these functions are in the standard library.  A program that cannot say anything to the user or cannot get his/her input is not an interesting program.  What would be the use of a program in which the only thing you can get from it is the time it takes to execute (I think this is one of the few things you can do without communicating with it)