# gcc -E generating intermediate files for a c source file but EXCLUDE standard libs with -nostdinc option

Tags: c, gcc, preprocessor

I am trying to compile `gcc` c intermediate file for a `calltree` generation using gcc `-E` flag.
This generates a preprocessed file to parse the functions.
However, I do NOT want stdlib functions in the intermediate file so I am using -nostdinc flag.

`gcc -E <FILE_NAME.c> -nostdinc -o <FILE_NAME.i>`

This gives me a fatal error (no such file or dir) and TERMINATES the compilation.

> <FILE_NAME.c>:46:10: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
> 46 | #include <errno.h>
> compilation terminated.

Is there any way I can force preprocessing to complete because I simply do not care about std include files not being found because I am not interested in parsing them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

I tried a few compile flags to suppress errors but no help.

Comment: Perhaps ```-nostdlib``` flag.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43051368/5821185)

Comment: *<FILE_NAME.c>:46:10: fatal error: errno.h*?!?  Does your code `#include <errno.h>`?